# can model.h5 file can be reverse engineered using tools like HDFview?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, hdf5

Can *h5* files can be reverse engineered using tools like *HDFview*?

And can a similar model can be created from information gathered from reverse engineering ?

Comment: Yes, very likely, the model information is saved inside the HDF5 and it is very easy to recover.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse engineer"? As I understand, `model.h5` saves the weights after training. So, you can save them, then use later to test and/or classify new data. However, you can't recover the original training data -- just the weights calculated from training.

Comment: An H5 file does not only store the weights but also the model structure, so you can load the model file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of searching for an answer. Finally I published a POC in [GitHub repository](https://github.com/alexdevassy/Machine_Learning_CTF_Challenges/tree/master/Fourtune_ML_CTF_Challenge/Solution)  where attacker has to extract information form model.h5 file using tools such as HDFView in order to bypass the web application's identity verification mechanism.

The information extracted by attacker includes:

- What does the Architecture of model file look like?
- What was the model trained with?
- What is happening / for what does model do?

For the detailed description of procedure visit [Fourtune_ML_CTF_Challenge](https://github.com/alexdevassy/Machine_Learning_CTF_Challenges/tree/master/Fourtune_ML_CTF_Challenge/Solution)